# Raw nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to create a raw nested aggregation in ElasticSearch, but I'm enable to get it working.

My documents look like this :

```
{
    "_index": "items",
    "_type": "frame_spec",
    "_id": "19770602001",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "item_type_name": "frame_spec",
      "status": "published",
      "creation_date": "2016-02-18T11:19:15Z",
      "last_change_date": "2016-02-18T11:19:15Z",
      "publishing_date": "2016-02-18T11:19:15Z",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "brand": "Sun"
        },
        {
          "model": "Sunglasses1"
        },
        {
          "eyesize": "56"
        },
        {
          "opc": "19770602001"
        },
        {
          "madein": "UNITED KINGDOM"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is to aggregate based on one of the attributes. I can't do a normal aggregation with "attributes.model" (for example) because some of them contain spaces. So I've tried using the "raw" property but it appears that ES considers it as a normal property and does not return any result.

This is what I've tried :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.brand.raw"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no result.

Have you any solution I could use for this problem ?

Comment: You need to modify your mapping in order to include that `raw` field. What is your current mapping, i.e. what do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/items`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Here is the current mapping : http://pastebin.com/tcebxJaL The problem is that those fields are not fixed

Comment: Which of those attributes do you wish to be able to perform terms aggregations on? All of them or only a few ones?

Comment: I would like to perform aggregations on all of them.

Comment: Are they all string fields?

Comment: Nope, some of them can be integers, as eyesize. Depeding on the complexity, if it's simpler  to have only some fields indexed, and only string fields, it might be possible. Just let me know what are the options.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`dynamic_template`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) in your mapping that will catch all `attributes.*` string fields and create a `raw` sub-field for all of them. For other types than string, you don't really need `raw` fields. You need to delete your current index and then recreate it with this:

```
DELETE items

PUT items
{
  "mappings": {
    "frame_spec": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "path_match": "attributes.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type":  "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After that, you need to re-populate your index and then you'll be able to run this:

```
POST /items/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.brand.raw"
            }
        }
    }
}
```